# python dataframe groupby transform with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Type1 | 10 | Red |
| A | Type1 | 20 | Blue |
| A | Type2 | 10 | Blue |
| A | Type2 | 10 | Red |
| A | Type2 | 30 | Blue |
| B | Type1 | 70 | Blue |
| B | Type1 | 10 | Red |
| B | Type2 | 19 | Yellow |
| B | Type2 | 50 | Blue |
| B | Type2 | 12 | Yellow |
| B | Type2 | 15 | Blue |

I would like to use groupby (ColA and ColB)  and transform with condition based on ColD="Blue" to calculate avg ColC into ColE, and I've already made sure each ColA and Colb combination must contains one "Blue" in ColD.

What I would like to get:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Type1 | 10 | Red | 20 |
| A | Type1 | 20 | Blue | 20 |
| A | Type2 | 10 | Blue | 20 |
| A | Type2 | 10 | Red | 20 |
| A | Type2 | 30 | Blue | 20 |
| B | Type1 | 70 | Blue | 70 |
| B | Type1 | 10 | Red | 70 |
| B | Type2 | 19 | Yellow | 37.5 |
| B | Type2 | 50 | Blue | 37.5 |
| B | Type2 | 12 | Yellow | 37.5 |
| B | Type2 | 15 | Blue | 37.5 |

So far, I am successful on groupby + transform, but adding condition on ColD throw it off, any ideas?

I've tried without condition on `df.groupby(['ColA', 'ColB'])['ColC'].transform('mean')`
but don't know how to add condition ColD= "Blue" into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mask` the values in `ColC` where `ColD` is not `Blue` then do `groupby` and `transform` on masked column

```
m = df['ColD'] != 'Blue'
df['ColE'] = df['ColC'].mask(m).groupby([df['ColA'], df['ColB']]).transform('mean')
```

---

```
   ColA   ColB  ColC    ColD  ColE
0     A  Type1    10     Red  20.0
1     A  Type1    20    Blue  20.0
2     A  Type2    10    Blue  20.0
3     A  Type2    10     Red  20.0
4     A  Type2    30    Blue  20.0
5     B  Type1    70    Blue  70.0
6     B  Type1    10     Red  70.0
7     B  Type2    19  Yellow  32.5
8     B  Type2    50    Blue  32.5
9     B  Type2    12  Yellow  32.5
10    B  Type2    15    Blue  32.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's filter the dataframe by `ColD` column then do a `groupby.transform` to get the mean of `Blue` then do another `group.transform` to fill the other color.

```py
df['ColE'] = (df[df['ColD'].eq('Blue')]
              .groupby(['ColA', 'ColB'])['ColC'].transform('mean')
              .reindex(df.index)
              .groupby([df['ColA'], df['ColB']])
              .transform(lambda col: col.ffill().bfill()))
```

```
print(df)

   ColA   ColB  ColC    ColD  ColE
0     A  Type1    10     Red  20.0
1     A  Type1    20    Blue  20.0
2     A  Type2    10    Blue  20.0
3     A  Type2    10     Red  20.0
4     A  Type2    30    Blue  20.0
5     B  Type1    70    Blue  70.0
6     B  Type1    10     Red  70.0
7     B  Type2    19  Yellow  32.5
8     B  Type2    50    Blue  32.5
9     B  Type2    12  Yellow  32.5
10    B  Type2    15    Blue  32.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there! :)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(cola=[1,1,3,4], colb=[1,1,3,7], colc=[5,1,6,9], cold=['b','b','y','b']))

df['cole'] = df.groupby(['cola', 'colb']).colc.transform('mean').where(df.cold == 'b')

|    |   cola |   colb |   colc | cold   |   cole |
|---:|-------:|-------:|-------:|:-------|-------:|
|  0 |      1 |      1 |      5 | b      |      3 |
|  1 |      1 |      1 |      1 | b      |      3 |
|  2 |      3 |      3 |      6 | y      |    nan |
|  3 |      4 |      7 |      9 | b      |      9 |
```